# Webview from xml file

Tags: android, xml, webview, xml-parsing

I want to open a link from xml file. But here is some problem with strings

Here is my code

```
public class WebA extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;


    static final String URL = "http://example.com/1/http.xml";
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY = "link_url";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY, parser.getValue(e, KEY));
            songsList.add(map);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.loadUrl(KEY);
    }
}
```

There is a string problem, I don't get it: how can I solve it?

Here is my .xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<music>
    <song>
    <id>1</id>
        <link_url>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlmezywdxPI</link_url>

        </song>

        </music>
```

Here is a picture of what I see when I open the webview:

[image]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>"
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

and webcontent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="238dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think my problem with string .I dont see error , just need string summon url from xml.

Comment: post your xml layout, any errors in your error log?  post that too.  Why are you calling setContentView twice?  Post your android manifest as well - I suspect you don't have permission to use the internet in your manifest.

Comment: I dont see error.just need string summon url from xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the url saved inside your variable `KEY`, but this variable only holds the value `link_url`:

```
webView.loadUrl("link_url");
```

You should instead load your url like this:

```
webView.loadUrl(songsList.get(0).get(KEY));
```

Given that you want the url for first item in your `ArrayList` of course. You would need to make a better mechanism for loading different urls if you have more than one element in your `ArrayList`.

Why you're wrapping a `HashMap<String, String>` inside an `ArrayList` I don't understand.